# Does a convergent series lead to a convergent sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n $ is convergent then the sequence $u_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Therefore if the ratio test $R=\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}$ gives $R<1$ then we can conclude that $(u_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent, right?

Generally, if we can find that a series is convergent then can we always conclude that the sequence that is summed up is convergent, provided that it is not an alternating series?

Comment: I think you should make your question clearer. It is difficult to understand what you mean. If $u_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, then it means that the sequence is convergent and has $0$ as its limit. Is that what you're asking about?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you have the right idea.  Whenever
the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n$ converges, the sequence $u_n$ must converge to zero as $n \to \infty$.  This is true *even if* the sum is alternating.  Certainly, then: if $\sum u_n$ converges by the ratio test, then we must have $u_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Note, however, that the converse does not hold.  That is, it is possible that $u_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n$ diverges.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, then yes, you're right. The ratio test states that if the limit is less than one, the sum converges. I think you might be getting caught up in the terms.

Comment: What do you mean by 'getting caught up in the terms?'

Comment: @ShadowLights he means that you're getting confused by the terminology, but you probably have the right intuition

Comment: Oh, those terms, my initial thought was about the terms of the series...

Comment: I know that there are a few tests for determining if a series is convergent. But my question was about if can make any conclusions about the underlying sequence on the basis of those convegence test. In not sure if that is any clearer...

Comment: In any case "@"Logan Clark and @Omnomnomnom thanks for the clarification.

Comment: No, the tests are only able to tell you if and when the series converges. They won't tell you about the sequence itself, just about the series.

Comment: @LoganClark you're wrong about that

Comment: Please see "the term test".